# Hibernate Exception: @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class [java.util.List]

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, mapping

I have a MessengerData class which contains a list of resources. This is an example of the structure that I want to have:

```
 "messengerData":{  
  "fr":{  
        "messengerType":"ImageCategoryTitle",
        "imageURL":"https://assets.pernod-ricard.com/uk/media_images/test.jpg",
        "clickURL":"http://perdu.com",
        "videoURL":"",
        "brickSize":80,
        "textDatas":{  
           "category":{  
              "color":"#000000",
              "fontSize":14,
              "textValue":"Texte de cat\u00e9gorie en fran\u00e7ais"
           },
           "title":{  
              "color":"#D66060",
              "fontSize":12,
              "textValue":"Titre en fr, peut aussi avoir des markusp genre <b>bold</b> <i>italique</i> <s>strike</s> <u>underline</u>"
           }
        }
     },
  "en": 
     {  
        "messengerType":"ImageCategoryTitle",
        "imageURL":"https://assets.pernod-ricard.com/uk/media_images/test.jpg",
        "clickURL":"http://perdu.com",
        "videoURL":"",
        "brickSize":80,
        "textDatas":{  
           "category":{  
              "color":"#000000",
              "fontSize":14,
              "textValue":"Category text can be sized differently"
           },
           "title":{  
              "color":"#D66060",
              "fontSize":12,
              "textValue":"Title color may change"
           }
        }
     }
```

}

This is how I define my Entity :

```
@Entity
public class MessengerData
{
@Basic
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "notification-system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "notification-system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
private String messengerDataId;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "idResource")
private Map<String, List<Resource>> resources;
```

My problem is that I am getting the exception described within the title of this post. I used a map because that I want to respect the json format.

Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: `Map<String, List<Resource>>`: you can't have that in a JPA entity. Your entities represent your persistence model: what goes in your database, at the far right of the layer diagram. Your JSON represents what you get from the clients of your web services, at the far left of the layer diagram. In between those two layers, you have a service layer: its role is to isolate the clients from the gory details of your persistence layer, and to isolate the persistence layer from the gory details of the client-communication layer.

Comment: Use that service layer to get the JSON, and save it in a proper way in the relational database, which should be designed with the JPA and relational databases best practices. Not based on what you happen to receive as JSON.

Comment: could you tell me why I can't use this structure **Map<String, List<Resource>> resources** for jpa persistance ?

Comment: Because that's not something that is supported by JPA. Remember: JPA is not about taking whatever class and save it. It's about mapping properly designed database tables to entities.

Comment: but I found some examples on internet explaining how to map an association as a map, like this one for example [https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/map-association-java-util-map/].

Comment: You can have a Map<String, Resource>, but not a Map<String, List<Resource>>. Those are not the same things.